# How to use conditional formatting in excel based off of another table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight cells in column G based off of whether or not the cell contains any of the text strings I have entered into another table, specifically the Pgroup table in Column U. I would like this to become a flexible conditional format based on text strings that can be added to or subtracted from the secondary table based on a project basis. I have tried a couple different ways but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated. I know I can enter another condition for every text string but thought this would be a better alternative since my text strings can change regularly. I am trying to do this with different columns and different reference tables as well but if I can find a way to make it work with one I think it will work with all. Not all will be absolute matches, I'd also like to be able to search for text strings inside of a cell that contains more than just the text string I'm looking for.
[My File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6tfn.png)

Comment: what have you tried formula-wise? 
You might try an If() statement in the conditional just to see if it works.
Then move up to index-match function (although I'm not sure if that works with conditional formatting).

Comment: =SUM(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&Mylist&"*")) is the formula I found on another website where you would alter the "Mylist" to whatever your table is named as a reference but it didn't work. I'm not very familiar with the index or index match functions. I've tried if statements but I don't know how to search the cell for a text string that wouldn't be a complete match so I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3793-excel-conditional-formatting-search-for-multiple-words.html#:~:text=In%20fact%2C%20the%20Conditional%20Formatting%20can%20help%20you,cell%20values%20are%20highlighted%20at%20once%2C%20see%20screenshot%3A  This was the website I was looking at for reference, maybe they describe it better than I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional formatting --> New Rule --> Formula  -->`=SUM(COUNTIF($A2,$P$2:$P$7))`
Where A2 is the start of a column to format and P2:P7 is where your values are located.
To format the whole row, set "Applies to" to $A$2:$endOfYourTable
[image]

Comment: Thanks for giving this a look, this didn't work for me. When I tried to use this formula it didnt highlight any of the cells even if they were exact matches

Comment: @Jack You're right; it only works for first value; also, the formula should be `=$A2=...` and the "Applies To" should be `=$A$2:[endoftable]

Comment: @Jack all set now. That works.

Comment: Is there anyway to use named ranges, like the table names to set the ranges? This sheet will have many different data sets and filters entered into it so I was hoping to have flexible conditional formats through the named table ranges. Only having to change the ranges is better than adding conditional formats for each and every text string but still a step away from what I was looking for. Thanks so much for looking at this Sam, I appreciate your help here.

Comment: @Jack - I do not believe you can use named ranges. I tried it and didn't work.  I think it's a known "issue" or shortcoming of Excel. 
One thing you could do is not us a $ for the column value of your end-point (e.g., `$P$2:$P5`)  That way, if the table expands the reference should "grow" with it

Comment: That's a really interesting way of doing it, I'll have to give that a try. Thank you for the time you've spent on this and your recommendations! Its much appreciated.

Comment: @Jack if the answer works, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: I got absolutely swamped with a couple side projects and haven't been able to try this yet. When I test it I will accept it or get back to you! Thanks for your help :)